# Event listener giving error

Tags: javascript

I have this code for example:

```
<html>
<input class="basketQuantity" type=number>Basket item 1</input>
<input class="basketQuantity" type=number>Basket item 2</input>
</html>

<script>
quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity");
for(var i in quantityInputs){
    quantityInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        console.log(quantityInputs[i]);
    });
}
</script>
```

When i run it i get the error message:

`TypeError: quantityInputs[i].addEventListener is not a function`

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: There are a couple of properties in the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which are counted when using `for..in`. Just use a `for` loop to iterate the list, not `for..in`. Notice, that your HTML is invalid, [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) must not have a closing tag.

Comment: Your for loop is not correct. In your case 'i' is a String. So what you are doing is: quantityInputs["0"] and quantityInputs["1"]. Instead of integers quantityInputs[0] and quantityInputs[1].

Comment: After you've got the loop working, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) is a solution to your second problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity");
```

First of all `quantityInputs` is the [`NodeList` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So

```
for(var i in quantityInputs){
    console.log(i);
}
```

will return all enumerable properties - from `quantityInputs` object and it prototype chain, not only its own (just `quantityInputs` enumerable properties). `for .. in` will return also `length` field and `item` enumerable properties from prototype chain and this properties are not DOM nodes and so don't have `addEventListener` method.

You must use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var nodeArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity"));

Object.keys(nodeArray).forEach(function (node) {
    // node.addEventListener
});
```

**OR**

or [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check:

```
quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity");
for(var i in quantityInputs){
    if (quantityInputs.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // quantityInputs[i].addEventListener
    }
}
```

**OR**

In the future (ES6) you can use in this case [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
var quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll("basketQuantity");

for (var node of quantityInputs) {
    console.log(node.addEventListener);
}
```

**Note**(thanks to @Teemu):

Also you have a error in your handler with `i`:

```
quantityInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    console.log(quantityInputs[i]);// return value of quantityInputs last i
});
```

so better use `this` for `addEventListener` target:

```
quantityInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating on a nodeList:

```
 quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity");
    [].forEach.call(quantityInputs, function (e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log("hello")
        }, false)
    })
```

Comment: Notice, that OP needs a correct value of `i` in event handler, not "hello".

Comment: The question is not about writing "hello" instead of "foo" or otherwise, it's about binding an event to an element.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript for/in statement loops through the properties of an object, so your `var i` sometimes receives properties of the array `quantityInputs`, like length.

Just change your loop to a convencional, like `for (i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {...` and it should works:

```
quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".basketQuantity");
for (i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    quantityInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        console.log('foo');
    });
}
```

Take a look here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: This is just an example, but if you need `quantityInputs[i]` then `this` is equivalent in this context, so you can use `console.log(this)`